# Pandas: Faster method than rollforward?

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing some data for cohort analysis. The information I have is similar to the fake data set that can be generated with the code below:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# prepare some fake data to build frames
subscription_prices = [x - 0.05 for x in range(100, 500, 25)]
companies = ['initech','ingen','weyland','tyrell']
starting_periods = ['2014-12-10','2015-1-15','2014-11-20','2015-2-9']

# use the lists and dict from above to create a fake dataset
pieces = []
for company, period in zip(companies,starting_periods):
    data = {
        'company': company,
        'revenue': random.choice(subscription_prices),
        'invoice_date': pd.date_range(period,periods=12,freq='31D')
    }
    frame = DataFrame(data)
    pieces.append(frame)
df = pd.concat(pieces, ignore_index=True)
```

I need to normalize the invoice date to a monthly period. For a number of reasons, it's best to shift all `invoice_date` values to the end of the month. I used this method:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df['rev_period'] = df['invoice_date'].apply(lambda x: MonthEnd(normalize=True).rollforward(x))
```

However, even at only a million rows (which is the size of my actual data set) this becomes painfully slow:

```
In [11]: %time df['invoice_date'].apply(lambda x: MonthEnd(normalize=True).rollforward(x))
CPU times: user 3min 11s, sys: 1.44 s, total: 3min 12s
Wall time: 3min 17s
```

The great part about this method of date offsetting w/ Pandas is that if the `invoice_date` happens to fall on the last day of the month, that date will stay as the last day of the month. The other nice thing is that this keeps the `dtype` as `datetime`, whereas `df['invoice_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))` is faster but converts the values to `str`.

Is there a vectorized way of doing this? I tried `MonthEnd(normalize=True).rollforward(df['invoice_date'])` but got the error `TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
df['rev_period'] = df['invoice_date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

Should be at least an order of magnitude faster.